# Fastest way to detect user agent

Tags: mod-rewrite, user-agent

I would like to redirect visitors to my domain with a certain user-agent to a subdomain. What would be the fastest way to do that? .htaccess / mod_rewrite?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you can match against the User agent using the `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` variable and a `RewriteCond`

For example, if you want to redirect all user agents with the word "robot" in it to the `bots` subdomain, then you'd do something like this, in either the vhost config of in an htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bots\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} robot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://bots.example.com/ [L,R]
```